# using htaccess to check for cookie on permalink then conditionall rewrite with query parameter

Tags: multisite, htaccess, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

On a wordpress site(also looking for multisite solution), looking for .htaccess to check for cookie being set, then if cookie is found add a parameter to the permalink. It works for top level, but any other permalink it wont work...been at it all day would love some input. This is Wordpress specific as I believe special consideration is needed for Wordpress that i am missing.

For instance if cookie found:
`http://domain.com` will properly rewrite to: `http://domain.com/?human=yes`

However what wont work, if cookie is found:
`http://domain.com/sample-page/` **wont** re-write to `http://domain.com/sample-page/?human=yes`

Here is one of my attempts.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cookie|cookie2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     !^human=yes [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?$ $1?human=yes [R=302,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Appreciate the input. Looking to do this via .htaccess and not hit the php wordpress site for a faster time to load.

Comment: While this would be better to do in PHP, **that's not how URLs work**. the `?human=yes` part isn't a part of the URL proper, it's a `GET` variable. `?human=yes` is just how it gets shown to humans. So you get `http://domain.com/sample-page/` with `human=yes` in the HTTP headers. You're going to need a http redirect to change that. Eitherway this isn't an Apache forum

Comment: >> While this would be better to do in PHP
Why? If I can do this before php has to load, and since it can be done without php wouldn't that make everything faster?

I've been searching for an answer, the way wordpress rewrites things I believe is why the standard ways of doing re-write rules aren't working for subdirectories making this specific to wordpress.

Comment: I didn't say it was possible to do this via Apache. What you want is not a rewrite, it's a redirect. Rewrites take a users input and change where it's routed to on the server. What you want to do is change the user input if a condition is matched, which means you want to redirect the user to `/?human=yes` if they have a cookie. redirects and rewrites are not the same. You will never accomplish this with rewrites